# Do all unitary matrices have fast multiplication algorithms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, unitary-matrices, fast-fourier-transform

One of the most widely known unitary matrices is the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix), which also has a well known fast multiplication algorithm $(O(n \ \textrm{log} \ n))$, the [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). Do all unitary matrices share the property of having a (not necessarily known) fast multiplication algorithm? Or is this unique to the [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix)?

Comment: An interesting question is whether the only unitary matrices that are "fast" are the DFT matrices.